# $! is not working for PID of last forked process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, background-process, pid

I am trying to start a process in background using --fork and it gets started but I also want to kill the process using PID. For that, I want to store the PID of forked process in .pid file using

`echo $!> pidfile`

But this is not working, just giving an empty string. I am attaching the code snippet also. Please help.
Thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
start() {
    mongod --shardsvr --dbpath /user/JCBLivelink/MongoDB/shardA --port 27020 --logpath /user/JCBLivelink/MongoDB/shardA.log --logappend --fork
    echo $!>/user/JCBLivelink/MongoDB/shardA.pid
}
```

Comment: You could use `pgrep monod` to get the pid of the process. It's not a neat solution, nor would be correct if there are more than one instance, but it's a temporary workaround that might work for you.

Comment: Daemons normally fork twice.

Answer (score 2):

`$!` only works when the shell is what creates the backgrounded process.  In this case `mongod` is doing it and the shell doesn't know anything about it.

That said, you can specify `--pidfilepath` to `mongod` to have it do that for you